# How can I use a bingInt (as string) as a parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, routes

So I'm creating a system where a visitor can ask my client for a music composition. The user starts to fill a form with details and such, and when he submits it, it's not yet sent to my client. However, he can get an estimation of the price, and modify his demand if he wants to. After that, He still can submit it one last time, and this time, the estimation is sent.

I don't want to use the default id as a parameter because it would be way too simple to 'parse' other estimations if the url looks ends with `/3` or `/4`. You'd just have to try a few URLs and if it's your lucky day, you'd get to "hack" an estimation that isn't yours. I'm planning to use a cron job to delete these estimations after a while, but I don't want to take any risk.

To avoid that, I decided to use the visitor's session_id as a parameter, on which I removed every alphabetic characters, but still saved as a string in my MySQL 5.7 database so that ActiveRecord would be ok with that. I also changed my routes accordingly, and the result is supposed to be something like

```
localhost:3000/devis/4724565224204064191099 # Devis means 'quotation' in french
```

However, when I try to get to this route, I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Devi with an out of range value for 'id')
```

Here is the relevant part of my controller:

**devis_controller.rb**

```
# ...
def create
  @devi = Devi.new(devi_params)

  respond_to do |format|

   @devi.status = 'created'
   @devi.session_id = session.id.gsub(/[^\d]/, '').to_s # How I store my parameter
   # Latest record returns '4724565224204064191099'

   if @devi.save
      format.html { redirect_to @devi, notice: 'Devi was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @devi }
   else
     format.html { render :new }
     format.json { render json: @devi.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end

# ...

private

def set_devi
  @devi = Devi.find(params[:session_id].to_s) # Tried '.to_s', didn't work
end
```

And here are my routes:

```
# 'index' and 'destroy' don't exist
resources :devis, only: %i(create update)
get '/devis/nouveau', to: 'devis#new', as: :devis_new
get '/devis/:session_id', to: 'devis#show', as: :devis_show
get '/devis/editer/:session_id', to: 'devis#edit', as: :devis_edit
```

My question is the following: is there a way to present the `:session_id` as a string to my controller's params? Or do I have a better option?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think session_id is a int at database, and then is where you should do the change.

change the type of session_id to string and ActiveRecord map session_id as string from then on

Comment: I already did this, it's now a varchar(255), so I'm supposed to set a varchar to the params, but it looks like it considers it as an integer

Comment: did you destroy and create again the database? Also you should do the change at sessions and devis tables

Comment: No I didn't destroyed the table but updated it with a migration, then restarted the server. Since I managed to save the `@devi.session_id`, I thought it was clear that it was a string from now on

Comment: `@devi = Devi.find(params[:session_id].to_s)` why u are using this?
Devi.find(expect a Devi.id) and you are passing it a session_id

Comment: I changed my routes as shown in my question: instead of an `:id`, the route is supposed to be waiting for a `:session_id`, but I don't know why it still asks for an ID in the error message..